# Adjective for "having to do with the plot"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on an assignment for English and I wrote the sentence.

```
"The quote is both thematic and []".
```

I'm attempting to find a word that fills the brackets and means "important to to the plot" or "having to do with the plot". Google and  dictionary websites haven't yielded anything of use, especially with the result spam generated because the term "plot" is included.

Does anyone know of such a word?

Comment: Welcome to the EL&U site! This, your first question here, is admirably complete and well-considered: you've included a fill-in-the-blank sentence, and indicated the scope of your prior research, both of which are strongly encouraged. Please do take the [help tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and note the kinds of questions and answers considered desirable and undesirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [relevant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relevant) which means **having significant and demonstrable bearing on the matter at hand** as defined in Merriam-Webster. The matter at hand is the plot.

Also you can consider [pertinent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pertinent) which means **relating to the thing that is being thought about or discussed.**

You can consider adding "to the plot" after both of them as it adds clarity.

Comment: +1; ""The quote is both thematic and relevant to the plot" sounds very natural.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the word [*pivotal*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pivotal) used this way.

> Pivotal: Of crucial importance in relation to the development or success of something else

A Google search of the word returns such results as:

> The first culmination generally occurs around the midpoint of the second act and is a **pivotal** moment in the story...

Answer (score 0):

The word I would use is [*germane*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/germane).

> Germane: Relevant to a subject under consideration

Comment: Isn't it germane?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ELU Stack Exchange. You will find that providing a reference and running a spell check before you post will get you more upvotes. For now, I've taken the liberty to edit your answer: I've added a link to Oxford Dictionaries Online and also provided the dictionary meaning of the word.